# I'm stuck on this Banking System console application C#

Tags: c#

About 2 weeks ago I started learning C# as a part of my education as a web developer. I have this assignment to create a console application that functions as a bank. So far I can create a customer, find a customer and show their info, account balance and I can deposit funds.

But I also need to be able to transfer funds from one account to another account, delete a customer and edit a customer. Right now I'm stuck at transfering funds. I hope someone of you may be able to help.

I uploaded my code here: https://pastebin.com/Hqyvjuuc

**Program.cs**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ShowMainMenu();
    }

    public static void ShowMainMenu()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Weolcome to the Bank");
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("1: Create customer");
        Console.WriteLine("2: Show Customers");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------");

        string command = Console.ReadLine();

        if (command == "1")
        {
            ShowCreateCustomer();
        }
        else if (command == "2")
        {
            ShowAllCustomers();
        }
    }

    public static void ShowAllCustomers()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("-----  All Customers -----");

        foreach (Customer myCustomer in Bank.AllCustomers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ID: " + myCustomer.Id + " Name: " + myCustomer.Name + " Money: " + myCustomer.Money);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("-----------");
        Console.WriteLine("1: Deposit, 2: Transfer, 3: Return to main");

        string command = Console.ReadLine();

        if (command == "1")
        {
            //deposit
            //first find the customer, then deposit the amount
            Console.Write("Enter the id of the customer: ");
            string customerId = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter the amount to deposit: ");
            string amount = Console.ReadLine();

            //now do the magic, find the customer then increase the money
            int theCustomerId = int.Parse(customerId);
            Customer myFoundCustomer = null;

            foreach (Customer c in Bank.AllCustomers)
            {
                if (c.Id == theCustomerId)
                {
                    myFoundCustomer = c;
                    break;
                }
            }

            //we might have found it
            if (myFoundCustomer != null)
            {
                myFoundCustomer.Money += float.Parse(amount);
            }

            ShowAllCustomers();
        }
        else if (command == "2")
        {
            TransferMoney();
        }
        else if (command == "3")
        {
            ShowMainMenu();
        }
    }

    public static void ShowCreateCustomer()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("--- Create new Customer ---");
        Console.Write("Please enter the name: ");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Please enter the id: ");
        string id = Console.ReadLine();
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.Name = name;
        customer.Id = int.Parse(id);
        //add it to the bank
        Bank.AllCustomers.Add(customer);
        //create customer etc...
        //eventually return to main menu
        ShowMainMenu();
    }

    public static void TransferMoney()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("--- Transfer Money ---");
        Console.Write("Please enter your account's ID: ");
        string id = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Please enter the Name of the person you would like to tranfer funds to: ");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter the amount of funds you would like to transfer: ");
        string amount = Console.ReadLine();

        /*
        if (id == Customer.Id()) & (name == Customer.Name())
        {
            //transfer happens here
        }
        */
        ShowAllCustomers();
    }
}
```

**Bank.cs**

```
public class Bank
{
    private static List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();

    public Bank()
    {
        customers = new List<Customer>();
    }

    public static List<Customer> AllCustomers
    {
        get { return customers; }
    }
}
```

**Customer.cs**

```
public class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        Money = 50;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float Money { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That seems like at least three questions - what have you tried (for each) and what's going wrong?

Comment: Congratulations on starting your journey on being a web developer. But please do not think stackoverflow is a place where you dump code and people fix it for you. We need an isolated problem to help you with. For example, what's going wrong here? What's "not working"? Which parts of the code specifically are giving you issues?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Some *specific* problem?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: you are using `name` as identifier of the recipient of the transfered money. What will you do if you have 2 or more customers in the bank who have the same name ? will you transfer to all of them?

Comment: the code you posted is not compileable. You are missing a declaration of the `Bank` variable. But beside that you need to loop through the `AllCustomers` list of the bank variable. And look for the sender and recepient of the money. Then you make there the transfer

Comment: Yeah sry, i was not specific at all. I just want to be pointed in the right direction.
in the transfer part, i want the id and name to be reconized so im trying to check if the id and name matches a customer.

if (id == Customer.Id()) & (name == Customer.Name())

I tried writing it a few different ways, but it wont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to implement the following:

```
public Customer findCustomer(int id) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Bank.AllCustomers.Count(); i++) {
        if (Bank.AllCustomers.ElementAt(i).Id == id) return Bank.AllCustomers.ElementAt(i);
    }
    return null; //Not found
}
```

This will simplify your life, because when you want to add/subtract money to a given account, or remove it, or edit it, you will need to first find it.

```
public void transfer(Customer sender, Customer receiver, float amount) {
    if ((sender != null) && (receiver != null)) {
        //Existent user
        if ((amount > 0) && (sender.Money >= amount)) {
            //Valid amount
            sender.Money -= amount;
            receiver.Money += amount;
        }
    }
}

public void transfer(int fromID, int toID, float amount) {
    Customer sender = findCustomer(fromID);
    Customer receiver = findCustomer(fromID);
    transfer(sender, receiver, amount);
}
```

You will need to find the `Customer` to edit and remove. All these are well documented and should be easy to implement if you are able to find a `Customer` by `Id`.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, im trying to implement it, but for some reason it give me a red line under receiver in the last 2 lines of the code. 'Customer ' does not contain a defenition of receiver and reciever does not exist in current context. So do i jsut declare it in my Customer.cs?

Comment: @VenGee sender and receiver are function parameters, you can call transfer with the known ids and amount and it should find the sender and receiver. I had a typo though, Customer.receiver did not exist, I have meant Customer receiver instead, but it seems my hands were disagreeing with my mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
public static void TransferMoney()
{
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("--- Transfer Money ---");
    Console.Write("Please enter your account's ID: ");
    string id = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Please enter the Name of the person you would like to tranfer funds to: ");
    string name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Enter the amount of funds you would like to transfer: ");
    string amount = Console.ReadLine();

    foreach (Customer c in Bank.AllCustomers)
    {
           if (c.Id() == id)
           {  
               c.setMoney(c.getMoney()-amount)
           }
    } 

    foreach (Customer c in Bank.AllCustomers)
    {
           if (c.getName() == name)
           {  
               c.setMoney(c.getMoney()+amount)
           }
     }


    ShowAllCustomers();
    }
}
```

I hope I helped. Good luck with the banking assignment.

Best regards,
Dimitar Georgiev

Comment: Thanks for the help Dimitar - it did not work, but u deffiently pointed me in the right direction!

Comment: Nice answer, Dimitar.